# jQuery looping through multiple forms

Tags: jquery

I have some forms which are creating dynamically and I have a common submit button, on that click, I need to loop through all forms and get the value of one particular element and need to get the sum. I have given some sample code below, the problem is, the code is executing 4 times, but Im expecting the loop should execute 2 times. what is wrong with this code ?

```
    <html>
        <head>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script>
            $("document").ready(function() {
                $('form').each(function(index) {
                    $('form > select').each(function(selindex) {
                        alert(index + ":"+ selindex + ': ' + $(this).text());
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form[1]">
            <input type="text">
            <select name="select[1]">
                <option value="1">One 1</option>
                <option value="2">Two 1</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <form name="form[2]">
            <select name="select[2]">
                <option value="1">One 2</option>
                <option value="2">Two 2</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just combine these into a single form?

Comment: Just change to: `$(this).find('select').each(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the outer loop -- your inner selector is enough to get data from all forms in the document:

```
                $('form > select').each(function(selindex) {
                    alert(index + ":"+ selindex + ': ' + $(this).text());
                });
```

Comment: Yes, effectively you're saying, "For each form, look at all forms with a select tag, and then do this"

Comment: Thanks for the help.. In that case, how to get the form id ?

Comment: @binoy Inside the loop, ask for `$(this).closest('form').attr('id')`